# Rails 3 'association :[...] not found' error for has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm pretty sure I have my models set up correctly for a standard has_many :through relationship...however, I used a rails generator for a model to create it and the first time i ran it, i accidentally created a model called `Categorizations` (plural) instead of `Categorization` and went all the way through setting everything up before i realized the error. I rolled back the migration and deleted the 4 files created by the generator (migration, model, spec, factory). I started over again and i'm still getting 
`Association :category not found` as the error.

my main question: 
**Is there anything else I need to undo because I accidentally created and deleted a model with a plural name?**

Followup question:
**If that's not the issue, then what am I doing wrong? Is there some glaring oversight because i've been staring at this so long?**

Follow up to the follow up:
**What else can I do to help troubleshoot this issue? All of the models are accessible in the console and seem to be set up correctly. is there a `rake routes` for model associations?**

Here is what i have in my view:

`<%= f.association :category %>`

I've also tried:

`<%= f.association :category, :required => true, :collection => @categories, :as => :check_boxes, :label => "Categories:" %>` (I have @categories set in the controller

Here are the models:

```
class PressRelease < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :press_contact

  attr_accessible :body, :summary, :user_id, :headline, :link, :press_contact_id, :publish_date, :subheadline

  self.per_page = 5

  def published
    "#{self.publish_date.strftime("%A, %B %d, %Y")}"
  end

end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categorizations
  has_many :press_releases, :through => :categorizations
  attr_accessible :description, :label
end

class Categorization < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :press_release

  attr_accessible :category_id, :press_release_id

end
```

**update:** This all works in the console:

```
pr = PressRelease.first
pr.categories
Category Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "categories"."id" = "categorizations"."category_id" WHERE "categorizations"."press_release_id" = 1

c = Category.first
c.press_releases
PressRelease Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "press_releases".* FROM "press_releases" INNER JOIN "categorizations" ON "press_releases"."id" = "categorizations"."press_release_id" WHERE "categorizations"."category_id" = 21
 => []
```

So the association seems to be working on some level. i'm getting more and more confident that i'm missing something little and obvious or giant and glaring. please help! thanks!

Comment: For this kind of situations you should run `rails destroy model Categorizations` or `rails destroy scaffold Categorizations` (if you generate a scaffold). In which view do you have `<%= f.association :category %>`? Is the form build over Categorization?

Comment: OOO. I didn't even know `destroy model` was a thing, so thanks for that. That view is in the `_form.html.erb` for the `PressRelease`...which is correct, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working over `PressRelease` you should use `<%= f.association :categories %>`, change the `:category` for `:categories`, because of the relation.

Comment: GREAT SUCCESS. Strange, I had tried this previously, but something else must have been broken as well because it didn't work then. Either way, thanks!